# How do I solve $e^{i+z}e^{iz}=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

The following equation $$e^{i+z}e^{iz}=1$$ is to be solved for $z$. I have tried 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
e^{i+z+iz} = 1\\
i+z+iz=0\\
z= -{i \over 1+i} = -{i(1+i)\over 2} = \frac12-i\frac12
\end{eqnarray}
$$
However I am absolutely unsure, that's correct. Somehow I suspect trigonometry should creep in the answer.

Comment: Don't you need also to use $e^{2 k i\pi}=1$ ?

Comment: This is not correct. $e^z = 1$ iff $z = 2\pi i n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sometimes *Mathematica* confuses so much, giving somehow different solutions from what I have calculated.

Comment: You had one solution but not all possible other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z=a+ib$ then the given equality becomes

$$e^{a+(b+1)i}e^{ai-b}=1\iff e^{a-b+(b+a+1)i}=1$$
hence we find
$$a-b=0\quad\text{and}\quad  b+a+1\equiv 0\mod 2\pi$$
so
$$a=b\quad\text{and}\quad a\equiv-\frac12\mod \pi$$

**Added** i.e.
$$a=b\quad\text{and}\quad a=-\frac12+k\pi,\quad k\in\Bbb Z$$

Comment: I am not sure I am familiar with the $\mod x$ notation. Could you explain what it means?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, now I got it

Answer (score 1):

You have $$e^{i+(1+i)z}=1$$ this means that 
$$i+(1+i)z=2\pi i n$$

So $$z=\frac{(2\pi n -1)i}{1+i}=\left(\pi n -\frac{1}{2}\right) (1+i)$$